# Show that there is only one $r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n + r = m $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $n ≤ m$. Show that there is only one $r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n + r = m$

Assuming  $0\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: If $m\le n$ then $r=m-n\le 0$ cannot be a natural number.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? It sounds a bit like all of humanity died and you have to reinvent all of mathematics from scratch, starting with the natural numbers. You have just defined addition and now want to invent subtraction but before you do that you have to settle the issue in the question in order to see that subtraction does indeed makes sense. Is that impression correct? In that case: what definition of $\mathbb{N}$ do you use?

Comment: If instead you live in our world where everybody learned about subtraction in primary school and we can take all its properties for granted the question becomes a bit empty. So what I'm trying to ask is: where does this question come from and what are you allowed to use and/or already know when answering?

Comment: You are a new member here on MSE, so you probably don't know how it works here. Just stating a problem will not get you far here. You need to show your work and thoughts on the problem, so those that have time to answer your question can see where you got stuck and address that. Context is important as well. Do you want a proof from Peano's axioms? Can you use associativity and commutativity? And so on. You got 5 downvotes and closure on your previous question and people told you there are issues with how you posed it. Yet, you post another question with no context or effort whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am assuming $0 \in \mathbb N$)
We proceed by induction on $m$.

Base case: $m=0$, the only other natural number $n \le m$ is $0$. $0 + r = r, \forall r \in \mathbb N $. So then $r = 0$ and is the only unique one that does this.

Now we assume this is true for all naturals less than $m$

We want to find an $r$ such that $n+r = m$. If $m = n$, $0$ does this, so lets assume $n < m $. We have then the predecessor to  $m$, $m-1$, is greater than or equal to $n \le m-1$. Therefore $\exists ! r$ by induction hypothesis s.t. $n + r = m - 1$. Applying the successor function to both sides we get $(n+r) +1 = m$. You can show that this is the same as $n + (r+1) = m$ by the definition of addition as repeated applications of the successor function. So we have shown existence and also since $r$ was unique by induction hypothesis, we can also note that $r+1$ will be the unique one that does this.